# Parse the following query string into json using python

Tags: python, json, django, query-string, w2ui

I have a query string with the following format:

```
 cmd=get-records&limit=100&offset=0&search[0][field]=number&search[0][type]=text&search[0][operator]=contains&search[0][value]=Mike+Jones&search[1][field]=name&search[1][type]=text&search[1][operator]=contains&search[1][value]=Mike+Jones&search[2][field]=role&search[2][type]=text&search[6]&searchLogic=OR
```

How can I convert this to structured json like the following (or similar):

```
{
  cmd: "...",
  limit: "...",
  offset: "...",
  search: {
    0: {
      number: "..."
      name: "...",
      ...
    }
    1: {
      ...
    }
    ...
  }, 
  ...
}
```

I have tried to use `urlparse.parse_qs` but it translates the query string to the following:

```
{
  "cmd": ["..."],
  "limit": ["..."],
  "offset": ["..."],
  "search[0][number]": ["..."],
  "search[0][name]": ["..."],
  "search[1][number]": ["..."].
  ...
}
```

The problem with this is the search fields.  I want this to be correctly structured.  The technologies I am using are as following:

Frontend:

w2ui table that requests data from the backend.  Also, as shown in this example, when doing a search it sends a request to the backend to do the search.

Backend:

Django.  The post request from w2ui is handled by a view which takes in the query string and acts accordingly.

Comment: The first format is not strictly JSON.  All JSON object keys are strings.  All JSON strings are double quoted.  I can see how the keys and values shown do not fit the requirements of an application that requires more structure, but the quotes around a string are correct. See http://json.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [querystring-parser](https://github.com/bernii/querystring-parser) package, which does exactly what you need:

```
import pprint

from querystring_parser import parser as qsparser

# I had to modify the query string you provided by adding a value
# search[6]; it didn't have one before, which caused an exception
query_string = (
    'cmd=get-records&limit=100&offset=0&search[0][field]=number&'
    'search[0][type]=text&search[0][operator]=contains&'
    'search[0][value]=Mike+Jones&search[1][field]=name&search[1][type]=text&'
    'search[1][operator]=contains&search[1][value]=Mike+Jones&'
    'search[2][field]=role&search[2][type]=text&search[6]=SEARCH6&'
    'searchLogic=OR'
    )  # NOTE: I had

query_string_as_dict = qsparser.parse(query_string)

pprint.pprint(query_string_as_dict)
```

The result is:

```
{u'cmd': u'get-records',
 u'limit': 100,
 u'offset': 0,
 u'search': {0: {u'field': u'number',
                 u'operator': u'contains',
                 u'type': u'text',
                 u'value': u'Mike Jones'},
             1: {u'field': u'name',
                 u'operator': u'contains',
                 u'type': u'text',
                 u'value': u'Mike Jones'},
             2: {u'field': u'role', u'type': u'text'},
             6: u'SEARCH6'},
 u'searchLogic': u'OR'}
```

If you want it as JSON:

```
import json

json_string = json.dumps(query_string_as_dict)
```

Comment: Beat me to it! This library looks great, but it's a shame arrays are being parsed as dictionary's.

Comment: @Ashley'CptLemming'Wilson, in this case it wouldn't work as a list, but I just tried changing the `6` to a `3`, and it's still a dict. I suppose it could detect incrementing keys starting from `0`, but there's not much additional benefit in doing that anyway, if any.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps take a look at this library: [querystring-parser](https://github.com/bernii/querystring-parser)

It takes `section[1]['words'][2]=a&section[0]['words'][2]=a&section[0]['words'][2]=b` and converts it to `{u'section': {0: {u'words': {2: [u'a', u'b']}}, 1: {u'words': {2: u'a'}}}}` which looks like what you're after.

Their docs for using it within Django:

```
from querystring_parser import parser
post_dict = parser.parse(request.GET.urlencode())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Django, you have this information structured like this on `request.GET` inside the view.